# remote execution in windows server via telnet

Tags: windows, telnet

I need to start a process and keep it running on several remote windows (03 and 08) servers. 
When I telnet in and start the process and sign out of my telnet session, the process dies.

I changed the registry settings so the pertinent tlntadmn output looks like this:
**End tasks on disconnect     :   NO**

restarting the service and/or rebooting the server have had no effect. My processes still die when the telnet session ends.

Any advice?

Comment: Well, feel free to mark this question as answered...

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to ask this question at [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com), which is similar to SO but focuses on sysadmin stuff. As I know near nothing about telnet, if you can't figure this out take a look at [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx), which will let you run executables on remote machines in various ways.